# How to combine find and within using Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, capybara

The following works as expected:

```
 within('h2', text: 'foo') do
      should have_content 'bar'
 end
```

I am trying to check within the parent element, using `find(:xpath, '..')`

Once you find an element, how to apply `.find(:xpath, '..')`, and then check for something within ***that*** element?

Comment: Why not just use a single XPath statement?

Comment: I find `'h2', text: 'foo'` more readable.

Comment: I was referring to your last sentence: Instead of applying one XPath and then another, you can use a single XPath.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you use XPath locator inside `within` it should start with `.` (if it doesn't start with `.`  the search is done not within `.myclass` but within the whole document).

E.g.:

```
within('.myclass') do
  find(:xpath, './div')
end
```

or:

```
find('.myclass').find(:xpath, './div')
```

Code from @BSeven's answer can be written in one line:

```
expect(find("//h2[text()='foo']/..")).to have_text('bar')
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//h2[.='foo']/..", text: 'bar')
```

Comment: If I use `'./p[@class=test]'` its not able to find, If I use `'//p[@class=test]'` its matching same element and another element outside the parent element.. Please help

Answer (score 6):

With the new syntax of Rspec after 2.11, it should be;

```
within('h2', text: 'foo') do |h|
   expect(h).to have_content 'bar'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The following is one approach:

```
 within('h2', text: 'foo') do
   within(:xpath, '..') do
     should have_content 'bar'
   end       
 end
```

Comment: The same can be done in one line: `find("//h2[text()='foo']/..").should have_content 'bar'`